# PostgreSQL: using case to compare values between columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case

I would like to compare two columns, A and B.

If Col A and Col B share the same value, I would like Col A to have a no value set.
If Col A and Col B do not share the same value, I would like Col A to keep the original value it has.

Below is what I attempted. However, it returns "true" for all entries in the case column - Col A (corrected).

```
select *,
    case when 'Col A' = 'Col B' 
        then 'Col A' = null 
        else 'Col A' = 'Col A'
        end as "Col A (corrected)"
from my_table
```

Comment: ´'Col A'` isn't a column, it's a string literal - and it will never be the same as the string literal `'Col B'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  case
   when col_a=col_b then null
   else col_a
 end as col_a_corrected
from my_table
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply do

```
select *,
       NULLIF(col_a, col_b)
from my_table
```

The `NULLIF` returns *null* if col_a = col_b, otherwise col_a is returned.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF